# Finding the sum of the most commonly occurring number in an array with best optimized time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, dictionary, treemap

If I have an array {2,3,4,5,6,5,7}, the output of this should be 10, as 5 is the most commonly occurring integer occurring twice. Importantly, I want to make this program optimized to its best time complexity while stating how I calculated it and also the space complexity, all in Java.

I am trying to use Treemap, but don't know is it the best solution or how to write the best optimized code in Java, along with other calculations. Please help.

Comment: Where is the code of your best attempt?

Comment: What is the expected output, when two entries have the same number of occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is with a bucket array, you run on your array once O(n), and count the number of appearances of each number.
at the and you find the maximum bucket and print - bucket_value*bucket_number.

Comment: I guess you are leaving out one core part of the problem: how to efficiently count the number of appearances. For that the straight forward solution would be to use a hashmap (key is the number itself, value represents the counter.

Comment: my solution was an array of bucket\counters, where you increment the array in the corresponding position. if you have a 5 you do array[5]++; but you solution is also a very good one.

Comment: I guess this is an interview question, and the obvious follow up to a response involving a count array, would be, "What if the range of numbers in the input is very large?"  And for that, the HashMap would be more efficient in terms of memory. So in terms of time complexity both solutions are equivalent, but in terms of space complexity HashMap is better.